# How to parse both of these date formats?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, lubridate

Dates formatted as `4/29/2016` are parsed correctly, but dates formatted as `6242016` and `2042016` are not parsed.

Does R think that some of the dates without the slash have day first instead of month?

I've tried including `dmy` in `lubrdiate` and it still doesn't work.

I've tried looking at `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` and it gives me `"English_United States.1252"`.

```
demo$date <- as.character(demo$date)
```

```
demo <- demo %>%
      mutate(date = parse_date_time(date, "mdy"))
```

Comment: `2042016` could be ambiguous: is it *"20th day of 4th month"* or *"2nd day of 04th month"*. And while it might seem obvious that the "0" should likely go with the "2", it's not always perfect inferring that in code. (I'm not guru-enough with `lubridate` to know if/how it would work there.)

Answer (score 3):

You can wrangle your dates all into the same format using stringr. Then convert to numeric and use lubridate to parse.

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

dates <- c("6242016", "2042016", "4/29/2016")
dates <- str_remove_all(dates, "/")
dates <- as.numeric(dates)

lubridate::mdy(dates)

# [1] "2016-06-24" "2016-02-04" "2016-04-29"
```

Comment: It's still saying 12 failed to parse. I want to parse the formats of both 4/29/2016 and 6242016.

Comment: @blaze I updated my answer to make the code parse both formats.

Answer (score 2):

```r
as.Date(sprintf("%08d", 
         as.numeric(gsub("/", "",  c("6242016", "2042016", "4/29/2016")))), 
         format = "%m%d%Y")

 # [1] "2016-06-24" "2016-02-04" "2016-04-29"
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
as.Date("2042016", "%m%d%Y")
```

returns `NA` as opposed to

`as.Date("02042016", "%m%d%Y")`

This is because the month has to be represented by two digits (00-12)

Try adding a leading zero for months in the range [1,9].